# Validation JSON schema runtime

Tags: scala, play-json

I want to avoid Runtime undefined behaivors as follows:

```
val jsonExample = Json.toJson(0)
jsonExample.asOpt[Instant]
```

yield `Some(1970-01-01T00:00:00Z)`

How can I verify this using partial function with a lift or some other way, to check thatits indeed `Instant`, or how you recommend to validate?

```
ex1:
val jsonExample = Json.toJson(Instant.now())
jsonExample match { ... }

ex2:
val jsonExample = Json.toJson(0)
jsonExample match { ... }
```

---

Examples for desired output:

```
validateInstant(Json.toJson(Instant.now())) -> return Some(...)
validateInstant(Json.toJson(0)) -> return None
```

I can do somthing as follows, maybe some other ideas?

Just wanted to add a note regarding parsing json, there some runtime undefined problems when we are trying to parse `.asOpt[T]`
for example:

```
Json.toJson("0").asOpt[BigDecimal] // yields Some(0)
Json.toJson(0).asOpt[Instant] // yields Some(1970-01-01T00:00:00Z)
We can validate it as follows or some other way:
Json.toJson("0") match {
  case JsString(value) => Some(value)
  case _ => None
}

Json.toJson(0) match {
  case JsNumber(value) => Some(value)
  case _ => None
}

Json.toJson(Instant.now()) match {
  case o @ JsString(_) => o.asOpt[Instant]
  case _ => None
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Option:

```
def filterNumbers[T](value: T)(implicit tjs: Writes[T]): Option[Instant] = {
  Option(Json.toJson(value)).filter(_.asOpt[JsNumber].isEmpty).flatMap(_.asOpt[Instant])
}
```

Then the following:

```
println(filterNumbers(Instant.now()))
println(filterNumbers(0))
```

will output:

```
Some(2021-02-22T10:35:13.777Z)
None
```

Comment: Thanks Tomer Shetah, is there a way like i suggested but with `lift` as a partial function, without the `case _ => None`?

Comment: Please note that `json.parse` returns`JsValue`. If you do pattern matching on it which is not exhaustive, you'll get an exception that is saying that. It is not a good practice. Therefore I think that using `Option` is better.